# How to use system installed packages?

Tags: python, python-packaging, gentoo, python-poetry

I am trying to write script, which should use Portage API. But Portage python package doesn't available in PyPi, but even if it were available that would not make any sense, because it should be used from some configured system with package database and configs.

I tried to wrote the following ugly enough code:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.6"

click = "^7.0-r1"

portage = [
{ markers = "python_version ~= '3.6' and sys_platform == 'linux'", path = "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/portage/" },
{ markers = "python_version ~= '3.7' and sys_platform == 'linux'", path = "/usr/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/portage/" },
{ markers = "python_version ~= '3.8' and sys_platform == 'linux'", path = "/usr/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/portage/" },
{ markers = "python_version ~= '3.9' and sys_platform == 'linux'", path = "/usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/portage/" }
]
```

But it doesn't work. Code in the **path** directory doesn't considered by Poetry as python package.

```
[ValueError]
Directory /usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/portage does not seem to be a Python package
```

Is there a way to do this and to use system as virtual environment for running tests (I understand that running tests in host system isn't a good idea, but there is a docker image with installed Portage)?

Comment: Re the last question, https://hub.docker.com/r/gentoo/stage3-amd64 maybe?

Comment: Looks like it's an issue with how the virtual environment has been created. With [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) I guess I would just use the `--system-site-packages` option, to be able to import `portage`. Not sure how to do similar thing with _poetry_. But there shouldn't be no need to use the `markers` or `path`. Anyway, I believe `path` should point to a location from where _poetry_ (_pip_) can download an installable distribution and install it. But _portage_ is already installed, and anyway `site-packages` only contains installed packages (and not installable).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks to me like it could be related to the virtual environment not allowing access to the *system site packages*. If it is indeed the case then note that this is not feasible with *poetry* as of today. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/1393), as well as a [pull request](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/pull/1982) though.

A workaround might be to create the virtual environment without *poetry* first, for example:

```
path/to/python3 -m venv --system-site-packages .venv
```

and then use *poetry* from within this virtual environment, since *poetry* is supposed to not create a virtual environment when it can detect that it is running from within one and will use it instead.

---

Apparently *portage* is not a *pip-installable* Python project, so it is most likely useless to specify `markers` and `path`. Additionally `site-packages` directories usually contain the installed projects, whereas `path` should point to a location from where *poetry* (*pip*) can download an installable distribution of the project.

I believe once the issue with `--system-site-packages` is resolved then *portage* could be listed as a simple dependency `portage = "*"`.

Comment: Yes, it did. Thanks!